# DocuSign Templates in Salesforce Documents

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I've seen a few questions somewhat related to this, but no clear answer.  This documentation makes it appear that Salesforce Documents can be used to grab a document for signature: https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-embedded-sending-signing#1-create-and-send-envelope

However, when looking at the Apex Toolkit, it seems you still need to use the template methods to get a template from DocuSign with the signature tags.

I would ideally like to get this template from Salesforce if possible.  Can anyone confirm if this is possible or if it's required the template live in DocuSign proper.

If it CAN live in Salesforce, how would I go about adding the anchor tags for signature and date?

Answer (score 0):

manual tab placement is not available in the Apex Toolkit, but the Apex Toolkit does support anchor tagging you can't supply positional data, but you can use anchor strings to auto-tag a doc on the way out

Comment: It looks like in the apex toolkit you can specify text to search for such as "sign here" and then it will place the sign tag wherever it finds that text in the document.  There are parameters for page number for example, but found out you don't need to use those, it can find them even in a PDF.